# Practical examples of pricing Mid-Curve Swaptions

Tags: swaption

Are there any books or papers that run through practical examples of Mid-Curve Swaption pricing, and their liquidity in the market? So I can match the theory to the practical.  Thanks.

Comment: For swaptions in general see this post https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/28108/swaption-pricing Then see this post "A swaption in which the underlying swap starts at a date materially after the expiration date is called a *midcurve swaption*" https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/28302/volatility-of-a-mid-curve-option